# Read and parse data from S3 PutRequest using Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-webflux

I have a stub setup to handle tests that interact with AWS S3 buckets. The (custom) stub implementation uses Spring WebFlux to respond to e.g. S3 put-requests.

Lately I have been forced to change my S3 implementation to use an `InputStream` rather than an actual file as input. My problem is now that my stub implementation doesn't yield the expected result when passing an InputStream rather than a file.

My stub is currently implemented like this:

```
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> putS3Object() {
    return RouterFunctions.route(PUT("/S3/MyBucket/{filename}").and(accept(TEXT_PLAIN))) { ServerRequest request ->
        return request.bodyToMono(String)
                .doOnSuccess { s3Stubs.registerPutObject(request.pathVariable("filename"), it) }
                .flatMap { response -> ServerResponse.ok().build() }
    }
}
```

The String passed to `s3Stubs.registerPutObject` in the `it` parameter contains the expected value "Hello World".

Now, when I use an InputStream as argument to the S3 API instead of a file the `it` parameter is no longer "humanly readable". It contains data like: `18;chunk-signature=c27c7fa381b8aa2824e8487979d2d0e9ded04dd3 ..... 0;chunk-signature=db7e8b1bacc57da0d410ee116` - where I would have expected the same result "Hello World".

I'm unsure if this is related to my Webflux implementation or how S3 is handling InputStreams in comparison to actual files.

Using the exact same S3 implementation using `InputStream` works when putting to a real world S3 bucket...

Comment: I've read this question multiple times and I still don't understand it. Your initial question seems to ask for `request.bodyToMono(String.class)`, but your "unrelated" info (which seems to be actually related to your question) seems to indicate you already know about this. Could you rewrite your question?

Comment: @BrianClozel Ok. So I could instead ask _why_ it doesn't work with `request.bodyToMono(String.class)`. But I think that would suggest that I haven't tried to solve the problem on my own. The problem with the above `bodyToMono` solution is that my String is "chunked" - e.g. it contains data like: `18;chunk-signature=c27c7fa381b8aa2824e848d2...`. I can confirm it works correctly using AWS and so I'm led to think that I need to modify my webflux implementation. The "chunk" part leads me to think that I have to deal with some Stream - hence I look into DataBuffer. Which might be completely wrong.

Comment: And again - I might be completely wrong and the webflux implementation actually does what it should and the AWS-end does something with the received request. I don't recognize that "18;chunk-sig..." value so assuming quite a lot atm...

Comment: This is getting even more confusing in the comments section. Sorry but I can't help here.

Comment: Well. Don't know what to tell you. Using bodyToMono doesn't work (ie. I can't get sense of my String) when using a Stream rather than a file in the S3 put request.. I guessed  it was related to my Webflux implementation and seeked help. No need to be condescending.

Comment: Just trying to help here. You haven't explained why bodyToMono "doesn't work", nor what input you're getting, what's the expected output and what's that String format you're referring to. Maybe the S3 community can help here, I've retagged this question to get more attention to it.

Comment: I rewrote the question to - hopefully - clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the AWS S3 SDK, it seems that the `InputStream` variant is also requiring some metadata, which should contain the length and base64 hash of the content. This is probably what you're seeing here being sent to your stub.

`bodyToMono(String.class)` really buffers the whole request body in memory and decode that into a String. For other wire formats, Spring relies on `Encoder` and `Decoder` implementations (there's one for JSON, another one for protobuf). It is possible, but quite complex to write your own, and probably not the best choice when writing a stub implementation.

If you want to really stub this, you should either accept whatever the S3 client is sending you, or read up about the actual wire format used by that client.

Now about your current implementation: it seems you're trying to do I/O operations within a `doOnXYZ` method. Those methods are called "side-effect" methods, since their goal is to print some logs or record some state, but not do I/O-related work - and definitely not blocking I/O. [Reactor offers ways to wrap blocking code for that](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking).

Comment: BrianClozel thank you. The issue further down the line is that I need to be able to read and parse the String again from my S3Strub - so writing rubbish will just push the issue further down the line. I will investigate what S3 does and look into builing a decoder for this. In regard to my implementation the "registerPutObject" method doesn't involve I/O but merely updates a HashMap.